# Edit multilingual pages

Tags: kentico

Based on the document:

When you open the Pages application on a multilingual website, you can see the language selector below the content tree. Use the selector to switch between language versions of the currently selected page.

[image]

But my language selector is missing!!!!

I am using Kentico v10.0.11 with Based license edition.

I have set UK and US in my website.

What else did I miss?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you double check you have assigned cultures for your current site?
[image]

As far as I know localization should be accessible in the base license so this should not be an issue.

If everything is set properly and it`s still not working you could check event log and browser console.